# How to pop a tkMessageBox in a twisted powered server

Tags: tkinter, twisted, deferred, reactor, tkmessagebox

I have a server based on twisted reactor, and I need the following scenario:
the server can receive two types of request

- ADD(x,y) and returns a sum
- HUMAN_PERMISSION which returns true only if the human user approved the ip of the client

I am using tkMessageBox to ask the human user, but the problem is that it blocks the whole reactor and the server becomes unresponsive to other requests

I understand that I have to use twisted's deferred here in some way, just dont know how
this: doesnt seem to work, it still blocks the whole reactor

```
d = deferLater(reactor, 1,tkMessageBox.showinfo, "is he ok?", clientIp)
d.addCallback(confirmUser)
```

Comment: Did you do the tksupport.install(tkinstance)?

Answer (score 0):

Deferreds can't do anything to make your code non-blocking.  All they can do is manage a callback chain based on an *existing* non-blocking event.  That's what lets you translate low-level events like "some bytes were received" or "a connection was lost" or "a user clicked on a button" into high level events like "the HTTP request was responded to" or "the user answered your question".  `deferLater`, for example, simply fires its `Deferred` when some time has passed.

You don't need a reactor to use a `Deferred`, even.  For example:

```
>>> from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
>>> d = Deferred()
>>> def transformResult(result):
...     return result + 5
... 
>>> d.addCallback(transformResult)
<Deferred at 0x100521200>
>>> def itsDone(result):
...     print("It's done: " + str(result))
... 
>>> d.addCallback(itsDone)
<Deferred at 0x100521200>
>>> d.callback(3)
It's done: 8
>>>
```

You can call `callback()` from anywhere; it's just *usually* called from a reactor event.  In your case, you probably want to call `callback` from a `Tk` event instead.

All that said, you need a way to get `Tk` events into the main reactor thread, which you do by using a reactor that knows about `Tk`'s mainloop.  A commenter already mentioned that there is an existing API for this: [`twisted.internet.tksupport`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.tksupport.html).  Given that `Tk` is not the most popular GUI these days, you may find some issues, so please [report them](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/newticket) if you find any.